# Node.js express server not able to read css files in my html

Tags: html, css, node.js

I've made a node.js server and its working to send an image and a css file along with my html website. The image loads fine but I get a popup on Firefox that says style-sheet could not be loaded. For debugging I put the same css path in a Iframe it opens just fine.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Repo</title>
    <!-- DOESNT WORK!!! -->
    <style src="style.css" type="text/css"></style> 
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0;">
    <img src="MazeBackground.png" alt="" srcset="">
    <iframe src="style.css" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <!-- WORKS!?!?!?!? -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my node

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const mime = require("mime");
const app = express();


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  app.use(express.static('public'))
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server is listening on port 3000."));
```

I tried setting the mimetype to text/css and sending the css file on its own. I just ended up breaking everything.

Comment: Have you tried changing the path of your css file? `./style.css` or an absolute path `/style.css`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must create your server like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const mime = require("mime");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')) // put static middleware outside of get route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server is listening on port 3000."));
```

Comment: your welcome normally you must add your static middleware on top of all your routes cause express executes routes in order top to bottom

Answer (score 4):

You dont need the `<style>` tag, it is for inline CSS. What you need is the `<link>` tag.

HTML `<link>` tag requires `href` instead of `src`.
So you have to modify your code accordingly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

W3Schools reference: [w3schools reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Comment: I tried that as well, Same error

Comment: That with the other comment actually fixed it! Thank you